# Common word for Help and Feedback in a mobile app

Tags: word-request

Is there a common word for "Help" and "Feedback" on a mobile app that can be used to group them as one screen?

I am building a mobile app, and because of the small amount of buttons on each page, I want to combine them into one screen, and "Help & Feedback" is too long. I need another heading for the screen that includes both getting help about the app and giving feedback about the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I would suggest to group them under a [Support] button. Most apps and many websites have such a section.**

If a user needs help with the app, they require *support*. If a user wishes to provide positive feedback, they wish to show their *support* for the project. If a user wishes to ruin your day with an angry rant about the various shortcomings of your app, they believe you require *support* in the development process.

**An alternative may be [Meta].** As you probably already know, all Stack Exchange sites have a meta site where users can find helpful resources and complain about diverse matters. However, this is a rather broad term and the purpose of the button is not immediately clear from the label.

I would use [Support].

Comment: Linked in my support screen is my own forum (called Meta) but “Support” is absolutely perfect because I can also put my donate button there.

Answer (score 0):

One possible common term is "Reflection" or more specifically "App Reflection" for the app - the user is reflecting on the app's quality by giving feedback, or the user is reflecting on how to use the app by getting help.

Comment: I have never seen this expression used for this and would not know what it meant, despite me being a native speaker. Do you have any examples of it being used?

Comment: @Laurel I haven't either; I thought of this myself. But I think it definitely serves as a common word between Help and Feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The two actions are way different from each other and I don't suppose it is possible to combine them into a single recognizable and understandable term.

"Help" means asking for assistance or support, looking for an answer to a question, seeking a solution to an issue or a problem. Buttons with captions like FAQ, Support, Help are often reflecting these actions.

"Feedback" is more about giving an opinion about the software, providing a review or an overview, rating it, commenting on the quality, the functionality, the usability, and the performance of an application.

The best solution for you would be either to replace them both with just a link to Google Store where you would have the email for contacting you in case any help needs to be provided, or concatenate them as you proposed.